# why babel-loader is part of webpack instead babel itself?

Tags: javascript, webpack, build, babeljs, babel-loader

I am learning about how build system works in JavaScript. If `babel-loader` is transpiler that translates `React` to `JavaScript`, why is it part of `webpack` plugin?

Isn't `transpiling` and `bundling` is a separate process?

And is there a resource that explain how all this frameworks fit together and make build system work in detail? I seem to only find high level overview at the official docs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Webpack is a "module bundler". On its own it does not change the source of a program (note: there are some caveats to this, e.g. minification), only join all the different bits of a large codebase together for easier and more efficient delivery over the Internet (depending on the use case; you may be bundling server-side code, in which case the benefits are mostly around being able to consolidate build tooling).
- A webpack loader is used to process files during bundling. It is specific to webpack (you would not use `babel-loader` without webpack, except maybe in cases of interop with other build tools, but even then it would not be used on its own).
- In a webpack configuration one specifies a mapping of file extensions to webpack loaders. For example, a common case is to process `.ts` files using `ts-loader`. This way, webpack will pass off files with the `.ts` extension to the TypeScript compiler, and use the output of this compilation in the bundle, instead of the source program.
- Babel is a compiler; it takes an ESNext program and produces an equivalent ES3+ compatible program.
- `babel-loader` does what `ts-loader` does for TypeScript; passes off files to the Babel compiler, and returns the result to be used in the bundle in-place of the original source program.

> Isn't transpiling and bundling is a separate process?

Yes. That is why we have "webpack the bundler", and "Babel the compiler/transpiler", and `babel-loader` to connect the two together. Without `babel-loader` webpack would not be able to process files through Babel.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Makes complete sense. Thank you :)